# What is main difference in a portable external HDD and a regular external HDD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

I have an external 3 TB WD drive for backup. I think it is shot so I want to replace it. I don't need a portable drive but if they are more durable I'd like to get one. The cost difference between portable and regular is negligible at Amazon. Are there any issues associated with using a portable HDD for a Time Machine backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small difference. A portable HDD draws power directly from your computer while an external HDD draws power from a power adapter plugged into the wall. Durability will vary depending on quality. If you're using a portable device (such as a laptop) it is suggested to use a portable HDD so you don't have to plug it in elsewhere. It should also be noted that portable HDDs draw more power from your computer which may result in faster battery consumption on portable devices or worse performance on devices using a very little amount of power (such as a Raspberry Pi).

Answer (score -3):

hello Mr please note that *HDD* stands for **H**ard **D**isk **D**rive there are two types of hard one fixed and other is portable there is no difference between them just portable give you facility to move it from one place to another for use it on other PC(externally) but if you consider *SSD* **S**olid **S**tate **D**rive yes here is difference *SSD* hard is more faster than *HDD* and also expensive than *HDD*.

Comment: yea I know what HDD and SSD stand for. I can't afford a large external SSD which is why my question was about HDDs.  In theory, if there is no difference in portable and regular I could move a regular drive too, making it portable.

Comment: yes you can make it but please notice that your regular hard need two wires to connect one is called supply and other is use to connect with motherboard to work and portable use only one wire for supply and for connect to motherboard to work thats why people use portable any other question just notify me.thanks

Comment: This is not anywhere related to the question.